# chome devtools 'go to member' shortcut overriden by bookmark manager

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Any idea on how to force chrome devtools - sources - '[go to member](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts#sources-panel)' Ctrl+Shift+O to take preference over bookmark manager? chrome version [41.0.2272.101 m] on windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The go to member shortcut only works when you have a JavaScript file open already.

Answer (score 0):

This feature will become available upon opening the first source file tab - as I had closed them all, chrome had nothing to look up on. I was (unrealistically?) expecting the search to traverse all sources on the tree...